# Getting empty result for select statement in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

In this project, college have to search student who taken admission based on two parameters subject and marks I have written query but I'm getting empty result

this is the controller to search candidate

```
public function check_search_students()
     {
      $config = array(
                    array(
                            'field' =>'subject',
                            'label' =>'Subject',
                            'rules' =>'required|trim'
                         ),
                    array(
                            'field' =>'mark',
                            'label' =>'Mark',
                            'rules' =>'is_natural'
                        )
                   );
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<font color = "red">','</font>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if($this->form_validation->run()===False)
        {
                $this->search_students();    // another function
        }
        else
        {
            $collegeid=$this->session->userdata('id');
            $info['name'] = $this->college_model->get_student_name();
            $info['search_student']=$this->college_model->search($collegeid);
            $this->load->view('employer/view_search_students',$info);
        }
     }
```

Model college model

```
public function search($collegeid)
    {

        $title = $this->input->post('subject');
        $mark = $this->input->post('mark');
        $y=0;
        if($mark==0)
        {
        $query=$this->db->query('SELECT s.name,s.age,p.sub_title ,s.mark 
                                 FROM applied_subs ae, student s, post_subjects p
                                 WHERE ae.college_id=? and  ae.student_id = s.id
                                 AND p.id=ae.sub_id AND p.sub_title = "$title" ',
                                 array($collegeid)
                               );
         return $query->result_array();
        }
       else
        {   
        $query=$this->db->query('SELECT s.name,s.age,p.sub_title ,s.mark 
                                 FROM applied_subs ae, student s, post_subjects p
                                 WHERE ae.college_id=? and  ae.student_id = s.id
                                 AND p.id=ae.sub_id AND p.sub_title = "$title" AND p.mark="$mark"',
                                 array($collegeid)
                               );
        return $query->result_array();
        }
   }
```

view--->view_search_students

```
<table>
         <tr>
         <th> Name </th>
         <th> Mark </th>
    </tr>
         <?php foreach($search_student as $value): ?>
    <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $value['name'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $value['mark'] ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are messing with single and double quotes.

You need to put single quotes around values in SQL instead you are putting double quotes.

That is the problem.

Please check below:

Change

```
 if($mark==0)
        {
        $query=$this->db->query('SELECT s.name,s.age,p.sub_title ,s.mark 
                                 FROM applied_subs ae, student s, post_subjects p
                                 WHERE ae.college_id=? and  ae.student_id = s.id
                                 AND p.id=ae.sub_id AND p.sub_title = "$title" ',
                                 array($collegeid)
                               );
         return $query->result_array();
        }
       else
        {   
        $query=$this->db->query('SELECT s.name,s.age,p.sub_title ,s.mark 
                                 FROM applied_subs ae, student s, post_subjects p
                                 WHERE ae.college_id=? and  ae.student_id = s.id
                                 AND p.id=ae.sub_id AND p.sub_title = "$title" AND p.mark="$mark"',
                                 array($collegeid)
                               );
        return $query->result_array();
        }
```

to

```
 if($mark==0)
        {
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT s.name,s.age,p.sub_title ,s.mark 
                                 FROM applied_subs ae, student s, post_subjects p
                                 WHERE ae.college_id=? and  ae.student_id = s.id
                                 AND p.id=ae.sub_id AND p.sub_title = '$title' ",
                                 array($collegeid)
                               );
         return $query->result_array();
        }
       else
        {   
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT s.name,s.age,p.sub_title ,s.mark 
                                 FROM applied_subs ae, student s, post_subjects p
                                 WHERE ae.college_id=? and  ae.student_id = s.id
                                 AND p.id=ae.sub_id AND p.sub_title = '$title' AND p.mark='$mark'",
                                 array($collegeid)
                               );
        return $query->result_array();
        }
```

Comment: ,yep that was the problem, now its working fine.thanks

Comment: can't vote up see my repution :P..i m new on this site